# Custom Price (attribute) and addtocart

Tags: magento-1.9, price, addtocart

I have created an attribute `price_used` and the type is price. I know how to display this price in frontend, i use this method and it works ok:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPriceUsed(),true,false); ?>
```

I need to create a separate addtocart for this price, i have tried many things for example overide observer but it will affect also normal price.

What would be the correct method to make this work for my custom price and also not affect the normal price?

I do not want to use magento's custom options for products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `original_custom_price` and `custom_price` attributes of `Mage_Sales_Quote_Item`.

You could use an observer attaching the `checkout_cart_product_add_after`:

```
...
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <my_module>
                <class>my_module/observer</class>
                <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
            </my_module>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
...
```

And, in your observer:

```
...
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    $item->setCustomPrice($product->getUsedPrice());
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($product->getUsedPrice());
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
...
```

This will set `used_price` as price in the cart, but will leave the product price unvaried.

I did not test the code, but should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @RiccardoT , @Senthil for your answers, now i understand clear that i need to go with the observer method. I know that it might sound stupid, but how i add the product to the cart using the custom function?I tried     
`<a href="<?php echo $_product->getcheckoutCartProductAddAfter(); ?>">add to cart custom </a>`

Comment: You could use a parameter in the querystring and intercept that in the observer.

Comment: thanks, can you please give me an example for the query string?From what i understand i need new function in observer like `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('price_used') == '1')` and then encode it in the addtocart querystring url

Answer (score 0):

You can use catalog_product_get_final_price observer. Observer function would be some thing like this.

```
public function setFinalPrice(Varien_Object $observer){   
$product->$observer->getEvent()->get product();
$price = $product->getCustomPrice();$product->setFinalPrice ($price);
}
```

Then have your definition in the config.xml

Comment: This will affect the standard price, he does not want

Comment: Thanks Riccardo. He can have a conditional statement in there to check that. That way this can be skipped.